# Calling multiple functions within the concat function in XQuery

Tags: xml, function, xquery

I need to produce a DOT graph from the following XML.

```
<layout>
<layout-structure>
    <layout-root id="layout-root" orientation="landscape">
        <layout-chunk id="header-text">
            <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.01"/>
            <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.02"/>
        </layout-chunk>
        <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.03"/>
                    <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.03"/>
    </layout-root>
</layout-structure>
<realization>
    <text xref="lay-1.01"/>
    <text xref="lay-1.02"/>
    <graphics xref="lay-1.03 lay-1.04"/>
</realization>
</layout>
```

I use the following XQuery to generate the DOT markup:

```
declare variable $newline := '&#10;';

declare function local:ref($root) {
  string-join((
  for $chunk in $root/layout-chunk
  return (
      concat('  "', $root/@id, '" -- "', $chunk/@id, '";', $newline),
  local:ref($chunk)
),
local:leaf($root)), "")
};

declare function local:leaf($root) {
for $leaf in $root/layout-leaf
return concat('  "', $root/@id, '" -- "', $leaf/@xref, '";', $newline)
};

let $doc := doc("layout-data.xml")/layout
let $root := $doc/layout-structure/*
return concat('graph "', $root/@id, '" { ', $newline, local:ref($root),'}')
```

The query above works fine and produces the following graph:

```
graph "layout-root" {
"layout-root" -- "header-text";
"header-text" -- "lay-1.01";
"header-text" -- "lay-1.02";
"layout-root" -- "lay-1.03";
"layout-root" -- "lay-1.04";
}
```

The result is shown below:

[image]

Now, what I would like to do is to assign a set of properties for each element in the DOT graph depending on their properties, defined under the **realization** element in the XML, as shown below:

[image]

This would, of course, require the following DOT markup:

```
graph "layout-root" {
"lay-1.03" [shape="box", style="filled", color="#b3c6ed"];
"lay-1.04" [shape="box", style="filled", color="#b3c6ed"]; 
"layout-root" -- "header-text";
"header-text" -- "lay-1.01";
"header-text" -- "lay-1.02";
"layout-root" -- "lay-1.03";
"layout-root" -- "lay-1.04";
}
```

I have written two additional variables and functions to select and write the required DOT markup:

```
declare variable $dotgraphics := '[shape="box", style="filled", color="#b3c6ed"]';

declare function local:gfx($doc) {
for $layout-leafs in $doc//layout-leaf
let $graphics := $doc/realization//graphics
where $graphics[contains(@xref, $layout-leafs/@xref)]
return concat($layout-leafs/@xref, ' ', $dotgraphics, ';', $newline)
};
```

My problem is: how do I include the function *local:gfx* to the working XQuery script above?

If I simply call the function *local:gfx($doc) before *local:ref($root)* as shown below,

```
return concat('graph "', $root/@id, '" { ', $newline, local:gfx($doc), $newline, local:ref($root),'}')
```

The query returns an error that a sequence of multiple items cannot be an argument for the *concat* function; how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`fn:string-join($strings[, $separator])`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-string-join) for this, which takes the strings as a sequence instead. If you use `$newline` as the second parameter (the default is the empty string), it even inserts the line breaks for you:

```
string-join(('foo', 'bar', 'baz'), '&#10;')
```

yields

```
foo
bar
baz
```

Comment: Thanks @leo-worteler; I had tried string-join before but somehow managed to mess up the syntax.

Just to sum it up, the correct result is achieved with:
`return string-join(('graph "', $root/@id, '" { ', $newline, local:gfx($doc), local:ref($root),'}'), "")`